# concurrent RejectedExecutionException when using threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

Stacktrace:

> Process: com.saife.connect, PID: 6842
>       java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.saife.connect.controllers.authentication.saife.SaifeAuthServiceImpl$LogoutRunnable@ffe6ebd
>   rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@840ecb2[Terminated, pool size
>   = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2078)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:843)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1389)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:627)
>           at com.saife.connect.controllers.authentication.saife.SaifeAuthServiceImpl.logout(SaifeAuthServiceImpl.java:514)
>           at com.saife.connect.models.saife.SaifeSessionModel$LogoutRunnable.run(SaifeSessionModel.java:233)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2020-01-20 15:35:00.580 6842-6842/com.saife.connect E/ViewRootImpl:
>   sendUserActionEvent() returned. 2020-01-20 15:35:03.582
>   6842-6842/com.saife.connect E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent()
>   returned.

```
private class LogoutRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.finest("LogoutRunnable START");
        authService.logout();
        logger.finest("LogoutRunnable STOP");
    }
}


public void logout() {
    logger.fine("logout, initialized -> " + initialized);
    if (initialized.get()) {
        Runnable logoutRunnable = new LogoutRunnable();
        mainExecutor.execute(logoutRunnable);
    } else {
        logger.severe("Model is not initialized!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify what is happening, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: app is crashing using mainExecutor.execute(logoutRunnable); with exception concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Comment: Could you tell us, which line is a problem, according to this stack trace fragment? I suppose that line 514 is causing the problem, so we should dig around that. `at com.saife.connect.controllers.authentication.saife.SaifeAuthServiceImpl.logout(SaifeAuthServiceImpl.java:514)`

Comment: at com.saife.connect.controllers.authentication.saife.SaifeAuthServiceImpl.logout(SaifeAuthServiceImpl.java:514)